# What can be re-used when creating a video game like World of Warcraft?

Tags: intellectual-property, video-games

When creating a such game, what can be reused from WoW? I know that the character classes, resource types, and generic races can be borrowed, but not the characters, lore, specific races and ability names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## only ideas

No model, no line of script, those are expressions of an idea. Only the bare ideas can ve taken, and remixed with the own expression into something substantially different.